# Installing different Node version in wsl 2

Tags: node.js

I am trying to update my Nodejs to the latest version in WSL 2. My old version is v15.0.0 and is installed at `active : v15.0.0 at /home/sathish/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.0/bin/node`
My new version `installed : v18.1.0 to /usr/local/bin/node`

My shell is using the old one. I don't know how to make my shell to use the new version. What should I do to make my shell use the new version installed at a different location?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

```
nvm use <your version>
```

Read more here: https://blog.logrocket.com/switching-between-node-versions-during-development/

Answer (score 1):

the simplest solution
you should install nvm then using that install the latest version of node then
change the default to the newest version
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/set+default+node+version+ubuntu+nvm

Comment: Code sample is thin, could just paste it in the mesaage itself

Answer (score -1):

I just uninstalled all versions and then reinstalled. It works now. Thanks for the answer.